# Download apt-get binary (deb) and all dependencies for target architecture: armhf

Tags: architecture, installation, dependencies, apt, deb

I need ppp for a project I am working on but for a different architecture on device which does not have internet access. The actual problem is pretty explanatory from title. Things I've done:

- I've uncommented the deb-src mirrors in the sources.list file
- I've added the option `[i386,armhf]` (and of course `apt-get update`'ed) after "`deb`" in the sources.list file.
- `sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf`
- I run `sudo apt-get build-dep --download-only ppp:armhf` but get no result in the current working directory and I just get:

  `Reading package lists... Done
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree
  Reading state information... Done
  The following packages automatically installed and are no longer required:` ... (No errors)

Why is nothing downloading? It's hard for me to give the full output message because I'm running it in a VM and I can't get the copy/paste feature to work.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2):

My solution for the same problem looks like this (replace `THE_PACKAGE_YOU_WANT` with `ppp`):

```
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
apt update
apt download $(apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests \
                                 --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances \
                                 --no-pre-depends {{ THE_PACKAGE_YOU_WANT }}:armhf | grep "^\w");
```

The question is 2 years old, but I hope it works for future googlers! :-)